# Light node cannot connect peers

Tags: go-ethereum, light-clients, peers

I am running a full node in a testnet and I am trying to connect a light node. I am using the following command:

```
geth --datadir node1 --port 30313 --rpc --rpcport 3013 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --ipcpath node1/geth.ipc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal" --networkid 15 --rpccorsdomain "*" --ws --wsaddr 127.0.0.1 --wsport 3113 --wsorigins "*" --syncmode light
```

I am using `static-nodes.json` and `admin.addPeer()` but they dont work, but if I try to connect another full node in the same way, everything works. Any idea how can I connect a light node peer?

My Geth version is 1.8.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

It is necessary to add in the full node: `--lightserv`